# What is libpurple? What does it achieve?

Tags: networking

**Question**: What exactly is Libpurple? What does it do?

---

I understand that Libpurple is a big piece of chatting clients like Pidgin and Adium but, what does it actually achieve? Why is it so popular?

Comment: I've typed "libpurple" into my favorite search engine and this was the first result: [What is libpurple?](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple)

Comment: Maybe some insight why is is used over here>>>>>http://libpurple.com/what-is-libpurple/

Answer (score 1):

libpurple is the core abstraction point between all of the instant messaging protocols as well as the users interfaces to interact with them.  It creates a common API so that an application that uses libpurple can just call "send_message(recipient, msg)" rather than having to call the specifics for each individual instant messaging network.

Answer (score 0):

## Basic Information

https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple

---

It does not give a lot of information, but is the official documentation.

Hopefully someone else can specify to greater detail.

Comment: Please include essential information in your answer. If the link dies in the future, your answer will become useless.